# Only displaying distinct regexp matches in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying writing a function to parse hashtags from a string and want to only display each unique hashtag once.

I'm using the postgres regexp_matches function, and have tried various combinations of patterns to make it only show one instance of each unique hashtag, without much luck.

Say my I have a string which looks something like this:

```
this has #abc and also #def and another #abc and even an #bc
```

Currently I'm using the function:

```
REGEXP_MATCHES(mystring, '(#[A-Za-z0-9_]+)', 'g')
```

which returns

```
#abc
#def
#abc
#bc
```

How can I modify my function so that it only returns distinct/unique matches, and I get a set that looks like this?

```
#abc
#def
#bc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    q.hash
FROM (
    SELECT 
        REGEXP_MATCHES(mystring, '(#[A-Za-z0-9_]+)', 'g') AS hash
    FROM mytable
) q
```

Comment: try to avoid code only answers. including explanatory text is useful for future readers and more likely to be upvoted

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct`. There is no need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT match FROM REGEXP_MATCHES(mystring, 'g') t(match)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2f7043802b16006805dff6775593cad9)**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT match 
FROM REGEXP_MATCHES(
    'this has #abc and also #def and another #abc and even an #bc', '(#[A-Za-z0-9_]+)', 
    'g'
) t(match)
```

```
| match  |
| :----- |
| {#bc}  |
| {#def} |
| {#abc} |
```